# Ruby string slice index: str[n..infinity]

Tags: ruby

Easy question, but couldn't find it in the doc.

How do I slice a string or array from `n` until forever?

```
>> 'Austin'[1..3]
=> "ust"
>> 'Austin'[1..]
SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):2: syntax error, unexpected ']'
    from (irb):2
```

Comment: The latter will work from Ruby 2.6 and will likely become the 'Railsy' way of achieving this - see [here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611586/ruby-string-slice-index-strn-infinity/54027399#answer-54027399).

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Use reverse indexing:

```
[1..-1]
```

An element in Ruby (and some other languages) has straight forward index and a "reversed" one. So, string with length `n` has `0..(n-1)` and additional `(-n)..-1` indexes, but no more -- you can't use `>=n` or `<-n` indexes.

```
  'i' 'n'|'A' 'u' 's' 't' 'i' 'n'|'A' 'u' 's' 't' 'i' 'n'|'A' 'u' 's'
  -8  -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
<- error |                you can use this               | error ->
```

Comment: Nice illustration, however, your use of "valid" letters (i.e. ones existing in the string) is a bit misleading in my opinion since data outside the bounds of the string are really undefined. That could be anything, including non-characters. Anyway, +1 for such a well-explained answer :-)

Answer (score 19):

Use -1 :-)

```
'Austin'[1..-1] # => "ustin"
```

Answer (score 13):

Pretty elegant using the [endless range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Range.html#class-Range-label-Endless+Ranges) introduced in Ruby 2.6:

```
string = 'Austin'
string[1..] # => ustin
```

Hope that's handy for someone. Cuts a couple of characters from the best approach until now, and will be very readable once endless ranges are regularly adopted.

Answer (score 3):

If you assign the string to a variable, you can use length/size

```
string = 'Austin'
string[1..string.length]  # => ustin
string[1..string.size]    # => ustin
```